# AWS EC2 instance role attached but not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an ec2 instances running that is suppose to start / stop another ec2 instance. It was working fine but for some reasons it is not working anymore.

I have Role attached to this instance with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I even try to give to attach admin right for debug but it is not working

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So it seems the policy is not the issue. I tried to run the describes instance from CLI after ssh to the instance:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-123456789
```

I got AuthFailure error as well:

```
An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

I double check and the role with the policy is attached to the instance. When I run:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

I got

```
{
    "UserId": "AROQWFDSGO54123F7TD:i-00000000",
    "Account": "66666666666",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::66666666666:assumed-role/MyCustomRoleStartStopWorker/i-00000000"
}
```

So I do have the role I want but for some reason it is not "working".

Any ideas ?

EDIT: running the `aws ec2 --debug describe-instances 2>&1 | grep credentials` give more details:

```
[...]
2021-05-03 19:46:02,352 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: iam-role
2021-05-03 19:46:02,359 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - http://169.254.169.254:80 "GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27
2021-05-03 19:46:02,362 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - http://169.254.169.254:80 "GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/MyCustomRoleStartStopWorker HTTP/1.1" 200 1310
2021-05-03 19:46:02,362 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Found credentials from IAM Role: MyCustomRoleStartStopWorker
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>2454f40-6236-43ce-87fe-0ed694fessad</RequestID></Response>'
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

It does find the IAM role but got the `AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials` error

EDIT2: I tried applying the same role on another instance and it work, no AuthFailure issue. But I need it to work on this instance, why could it be not working on this one ?
There is no `~/.aws/credentials` file on the instance nor any `AWS_*` env variable

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything on the server that would override the IAM profile, like a `~/.aws/credentials` file, or `AWS_*` environment variables.

Comment: Check debug output e.g. `aws ec2 --debug describe-instances 2>&1 | grep credentials`

Comment: @MarkB I checked, I have none of those

Comment: @jarmod thx for the tips, I ran the debug output and update my message with the log trace

Comment: Which region are you doing this work in? And what does `aws ec2 describe-regions --region-names your-region-here` yield for `OptInStatus`?

Comment: Is this the issue with only this instance, or any other as well?

Comment: @jarmod running `describe-regions` yield the same error `An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials`

Comment: @Marcin, good point! I tried applied the same role to another instance and it works ! What's wrong with this instance ?

Comment: Which region is this?

Comment: @jarmod it's `eu-west-1`

Comment: @jarmod when I run the describes region with the same role (the one with admin right) on another instance, it works just fine

Comment: Different versions of the awscli on these two instances? Make sure the awscli is up to date. Plus here's a related [support article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-validate-access-credentials/).

Comment: aws cli version is `aws-cli/2.2.1 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.4.0-1037-aws exe/x86_64.ubuntu.18 prompt/off` on both instance except on is on ubuntu 20. Based on the support article, I added this `sts_regional_endpoints = regional` to `~/.aws/config` but still not working... I guess I'll try to contact aws support

Comment: ah but to have technical support, I need to upgrade plan :(